# Array to where statement

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to see the best way to create a where statement with a PHP array

```
$array = array (
  0 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'A',
    'ip' => '64.12.89.186',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  1 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'A',
    'ip' => '205.188.100.58',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  2 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'A',
    'ip' => '205.188.101.58',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  3 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'A',
    'ip' => '207.200.74.38',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  4 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'A',
    'ip' => '64.12.79.57',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  5 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'NS',
    'target' => 'dns-01.ns.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
    '6' => 'array (',
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'NS',
    'target' => 'dns-07.ns.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  7 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'NS',
    'target' => 'dns-06.ns.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  8 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'NS',
    'target' => 'dns-02.ns.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  9 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'SOA',
    'mname' => 'dtc-ext3.edns.aol.com',
    'rname' => 'hostmaster.aol.net',
    'serial' => '352455322',
    'refresh' => '43200',
    'retry' => '180',
    'expire' => '2592000',
    'minimum-ttl' => '300',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '1691'
  ),
  10 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'MX',
    'pri' => '15',
    'target' => 'mailin-04.mx.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  11 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'MX',
    'pri' => '15',
    'target' => 'mailin-01.mx.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  12 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'MX',
    'pri' => '15',
    'target' => 'mailin-02.mx.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  13 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'MX',
    'pri' => '15',
    'target' => 'mailin-03.mx.aol.com',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2466'
  ),
  14 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'TXT',
    'txt' => 'v=spf1 ptr:mx.aol.com ?all',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2465'
  ),
  15 => array (
    'host' => 'aol.com',
    'type' => 'TXT',
    'txt' => 'spf2.0/pra ptr:mx.aol.com ?all',
    'class' => 'IN',
    'ttl' => '2465'
  )
);
```

This is my Array I would like to make a where statement for on EX type = NS and so on then pass all that in to a variable to be displayed.

Please note if I do not respond to comment/questions, I will with in the next few hours my internet will be going down for repair.

Comment: Have you try flattening the array into a single dimension? and implode(array_fill($array,'?'), ',') to create parameterize prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [dns_get_record](http://php.net/dns_get_record)? If so, the second parameter restricts the type of record returned, so you could use `DNS_NS` to filter your example. Otherwise use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$wantedType = 'NS';

var_dump(array_filter($records, function($record) use ($wantedType) {
    return ($record['type'] === $wantedType);
}));
```

You could generalise this even more:

```
// expand as necessary
$requirements = array(
    'type' => 'NS',
);

var_dump(array_filter($records, function($record) use ($requirements) {
    // only include if all the requirements match
    return (array_intersect($requirements, $record) == $requirements);
}));
```

Or to group by type:

```
$groupedRecords = array();

foreach ($records as $record) {
    if (!array_key_exists($record['type'], $groupedRecords)) {
        $groupedRecords[$record['type']] = array();
    }

    $groupedRecords[$record['type']][] = $record;
}

// $groupedRecords now contains all records nested by record type
```

Comment: I am using dns_get_record I am trying to do EX a DNS_ALL so it will pull all the info at once then I need to break every thing up in to sections so it looks like and is readable.

Comment: I am getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/google/public_html/google.com/test3.php on line 10

Comment: See my edit for how to group the records by type. If you see the above error, I'm guessing you're still using PHP 5.2. PHP 5.4 is out now, and PHP 5.2 is no longer supported, but you can rewrite the anonymous functions to be named functions and use them as normal callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$param = array();
$content = array();
foreach ($mainArray as $item) {
  foreach ($item as $key=>$value) {
   $params[] = "AND $key = ?";
   $content[] = $value;
  }
}

$sql = "SELECT .... WHERE " . implode($params, ' ');
$statement = // Create prepared statement with $sql
execute($statement, $content);
```

Comment: Chuck There is no SQL in or any database for this. kinda confused on your statement

**EDIT** I have just tryed your code about and that did not work

Comment: @ken, you didn't tell us what you tables looks like, nor did you mention what db u r using. And $sql is your SQL statement, You asked for how to create where condition. the implode will create your where conditions

Comment: `$mainArray` in my code represents the array you have defined above.

Comment: there is no database im saying where statement as I need to search the array then group every thing and make it look nice, so the code would search the Array and fine type = NS then group all them into once section and then group all the type = A in to a another one. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Churk's solution if you have access to prepared statements through your DAL. Otherwise what I often find myself doing with building queries looks like this (using your $array format):

```
foreach ( $array as $query_key => $conditions ) {
  $query = array();
  $query[] = 'select * from XXX';
  $query[] = 'where ((1=1)';
  foreach ( $conditions as $key => $value ) {
    $query[] = 'and ' . $key . ' = \'' . $value '\''; 
  }
  $query[] = ')';
  $query = implode(PHP_EOL, $query);
  echo $query, PHP_EOL;
}
```

The 'trick' here is starting the where clause with '(1=1)' which is always true, then all the following equality conditions can start with 'AND ...'.

Cheers